# How can I use WIN32OLE safely from a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, win32ole

I'm trying to use the win32ole gem in a Rails 3 app and running into some problems that I think are thread-related.  Basically, I have code like this that I use to get user-specific data from our Active Directory store:

```
root = WIN32OLE.connect("LDAP://RootDSE")
```

But this gives a sporadic error when run as part of a Rails request (I think the first request after the Rails app has been restarted always works).  It works fine *every time* when I run this code from a standalone Ruby app.  I understand from a bit of Googling that this is down to the fact the OLE/COM object can only be used in the thread it was first initialised in (something to do with it running in an STA?).  From that I'm guessing that this is something to do with Rails 3 running different requests on separate threads? (My Rails app is running on a Windows box.)

The error thrown by the `WIN32OLE.connect` call is `'connect': failed to parse display name of moniker`.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally resolved this problem thanks to the information & code [here](http://cowlibob.co.uk/ruby-threads-win32ole-coinitialize-and-counin).  I modified my `win32ole.rb` file as suggested there to barf if `CoInitialize` wasn't first called on the main thread.  I achieved *that* in my Rails 3 app by adding a Ruby file to the `config/initializers` directory containing just

```
require 'win32ole'
```

That seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Ben.  This is the future talking.  The link you mention here is now dead.  I need your knowledge from the past!

Comment: Sorry I can't find that exact link again.  Even so, you shouldn't need to refer to it: just make sure you call `CoInitialize` before any call to create a `WIN32OLE` object.  The only reason I was hitting this in Rails was because of a threading race-condition.  Rails initializers can be used to solve this.

Comment: I got "cannot load such file -- win32ole" with the `require 'win32ole'`...